# Putting a local array changes assembly output for X86-64

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

When we have just an `int` variable in `main`:

```
int main() {
    int d;
    return 0;
}
```

Following code is generated for x86-64 on Linux by `gcc -S test.c`.

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170109"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Putting an array as local variable

```
int main() {
    int d[2];
    return 0;
}
```

generates a lot of extraneous code at the beginning which I am not able to comprehend.

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    leaq    -4144(%rsp), %rsp
    orq $0, (%rsp)
    leaq    4128(%rsp), %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170109"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Specifically, what are these instructions doing?

```
    leaq    -4144(%rsp), %rsp
    orq $0, (%rsp)
    leaq    4128(%rsp), %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, %eax
```

Comment: Most of the extraneous code appears to be stack protection related. Compiling your code with optimizations `-O3` if you want better looking code (in this case it won't do much except return 0) and if you don't want the stack protection use `-fno-stack-protector`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. I was unaware of this feature. I will look it up. Still is it possible for you to explain what this code is doing?

Comment: A reasonable explanation is in this [Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/security/anatomy-of-a-stack-smashing-attack-and-h/240001832) . There are 3 pages to the article. The code discussion starts on page 2.

Comment: Ok. I will read that. Thanks a lot!